# Unable define functor instance for ADT

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a library that parses a binary format into a Haskell value. The first step creates an ADT that provides extra type information over some primitive value. I've written a simplified version of this below as `Object`.

I'd like for users of the library to either treat this value as a `Functor` or have some other means by which to extract values from the structure. I've been unable to write a valid `Functor` instance for `Object`. Is it possible to do so?

```
data Object a
  = N
  | B Bool
  | I Int
  | L [Object a]
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor Object where
  fmap f N     = N
  fmap f (B x) = B $ f x
  -- etc.

-- GHC error.

-- % ghci Object.hs
-- GHCi, version 7.10.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
-- [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Object.hs, interpreted )

-- Object.hs:10:22:
--     Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘b’
--       ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
--           the type signature for fmap :: (a -> b) -> Object a -> Object b
--           at Object.hs:9:3
--     Relevant bindings include
--       f :: a -> b (bound at Object.hs:10:8)
--       fmap :: (a -> b) -> Object a -> Object b (bound at Object.hs:9:3)
--     In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘f x’
--     In the expression: B $ f x

-- Object.hs:10:24:
--     Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Bool’
--       ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
--           the type signature for fmap :: (a -> b) -> Object a -> Object b
--           at Object.hs:9:3
--     Relevant bindings include
--       f :: a -> b (bound at Object.hs:10:8)
--       fmap :: (a -> b) -> Object a -> Object b (bound at Object.hs:9:3)
--     In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘x’
--     In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘f x’
-- Failed, modules loaded: none.
-- Prelude>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
instance Functor Object where
  fmap f N     = N
  fmap f (B x) = B x
  fmap f (I i) = I i
  fmap f (L xs) = L $ map (fmap f) xs
```

or also, more simply:

```
data Object a
  = N
  | B Bool
  | I Int
  | L [Object a]
  deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)
```

after having enabled the `DeriveFunctor` extension.

Note that your `a` is not used anywhere, making `Object a` a phantom type. Is that intentional?
Because of this, you can not really apply `f` to anything, since you would need a value of type `a`. You are trying to apply `f` to a fixed type as `Bool`, but this won't type check, since `f` is of type `a -> b`, where `a` is the `a` in `Object a`, which does not have to be `Bool`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The `a` in `Object a` was to make `Object` of kind `* -> *`, making it intentional but probably misguided. I'm unsure if it is good etiquette to ask another question in the comments, but is there another way to write this ADT so that I can apply `f` to the internal values?

Comment: @unsymbol If I had a function `f :: Int -> Int` and some `omap :: (a -> b) -> Object a -> Object b`, then `omap f :: Object Int -> Object Int`, but how would you apply `f`?  You can't make a decision based on the type of `f`, so how would you know to apply it to the value in the `I` constructor?  Additionally, what if `f :: Int -> Double`, how might that get applied to the contents of an `Object` value?  Your best bet is to create a `bmap :: (Bool -> Bool) -> Object -> Object`, `imap :: (Int -> Int) -> Object -> Object`, etc, or just let users of your type pattern match on the constructors.

Comment: @unsymbol You need to use `a` in the definition of `Object a` so that you can apply `f` to it. Perhaps the real question is: why do you want to make `Object`  a functor? What is the problem you are trying to solve with functors?

Comment: Thank you both, your answers and discussion has been very helpful. I think it's quite clear that I'm trying to use the wrong abstraction for my current design. I'll re-think! /cc @bheklilr